# Error searching in Django admin

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-admin

Here is the relevant part of my code:

> model.py

```
class Blogger(models.Model):
    identity = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.identity.username
```

I want to be able to search for a blogger with their `blogger_instance.identity.username`, so I did:

> admin.py

```
@admin.register(Blogger)
class BloggerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'identity')
    search_fields = ['__str__']
```

I went to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/blogger/`, typed `user` in the search field, hit <kbd>Search</kbd>, and got an **FieldError**:

```
FieldError at /admin/blog/blogger/
Cannot resolve keyword '' into field. Choices are: bio, blog, comment, id, identity, identity_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/blogger/?q=user
Django Version: 1.10.6
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword '' into field. Choices are: bio, blog, comment, id, identity, identity_id
Exception Location: /Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py
in names_to_path, line 1327
Python Executable:  /Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/sunqingyao/PycharmProjects/diyblog',
 '/Users/sunqingyao/PycharmProjects/diyblog',
 '/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 28 Mar 2017 13:01:58 +0800
```

When I change

```
search_fields = ['__str__']
```

to

```
search_fields = ['identity']
```

I got an **TypeError** instead:

```
TypeError at /admin/blog/blogger/
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/blogger/?q=user
Django Version: 1.10.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
Exception Location: /Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in get_lookup, line 694
Python Executable:  /Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/sunqingyao/PycharmProjects/diyblog',
 '/Users/sunqingyao/PycharmProjects/diyblog',
 '/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 28 Mar 2017 13:12:09 +0800
```

What value should I set `search_fields` to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [search_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) documentation, so as stated there

> These fields should be some kind of text field, such as CharField or
>   TextField. You can also perform a related lookup on a ForeignKey or
>   ManyToManyField with the lookup API “follow” notation:
>
> ```
> search_fields = ['foreign_key__related_fieldname']
> ```

So in your case

```
search_fields = ['identity__username']
```

Also notice it doesn't say you could use calculated property as you tried at first

Answer (score 1):

Write your admin class like this

```
     #Register your models here.
     class BloggerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
         list_display = ('__str__', 'identity')
         search_fields = ['identity__fieldname', ]

     admin.site.register(Blogger, BloggerAdmin)
```

search fields must be like this `identity__fieldname`